# Protobuf-dt 1.4.3 not opening in eclipse 4.2 Juno

Tags: eclipse-plugin, protocol-buffers, eclipse-juno

I tried to use the protobuf-dt plugin, and I managed to install it using the "Install new software menu", but the plugin is not displayed when I open my .proto files.

The plugin is listed under the "Installed Software" tab in the "Eclipse SDK Installation Details" as the following entry:

```
Protocol Buffer Editor  1.4.3.201307151341 com.google.eclipse.protobuf.feature.group    Google, Inc.
```

Software update site: http://protobuf-dt.googlecode.com/git/update-site

Eclipse version: 4.2.2

Does someone know what might be the problem here?